# Ant use old jdk - how to change it?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have eclipse indigo (3.7.2) on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit and I try to compile project using java 1.7. I think I have installed java 1.7 properly because, I can run [processing 2.0](http://processing.org/) (which use java 1.7) and I get correct version message:

```
prokop@prokop-Precision-T1500:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)
```

however, when hit "play" in Ant in eclipse I get following message:

```
 Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

also in header caption of "Console" window of ant build output is :

```
[Ant Build] /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java
```

I tried to modify environment settings of eclipse:

- Project > Properties > Java Compiler to 1.7
- Window > Prefferences > Java > Installed JREs to jdk1.7._60 which I downloaded to my home `/home/prokop/SW/jdk1.7.0_60`

but it does not help - ant is oviously still using `java-6-openjdk`

- Is there any other setting how to say Ant to use jdk1.7 ?
- Is it possible at all to make eclipse indigo (3.7.2) on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit force to compile with java 1.7 ?

Comment: what "ant -diagnostic " result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This occurs when you run ant via eclipse. You can set JDK using External tools configuration in Eclipse. See the attachment.

[image: External tools configuration in eclipse]

Answer (score 2):

Ant uses `JAVA_HOME`. Try echo $JAVA_HOME in shell to see where it's pointing and point it to jdk 7.

Point 4 in following manual : 
http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html

Nice explanation can be found here : 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123412/what-is-the-difference-between-java-home-and-update-alternatives

Comment: Hi, I just dit that, I choosed  `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java` from the selection, but I got still the same output with ant.

Comment: Hello, i updated my answer. You already said you are using java 7 as your main jdk by showing java -version output.

Comment: My JAVA_HOME variable was not set, I set it to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java` and also put `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/` into PATH according to this http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/

but it does not helped. Just indika's recomandation to set eclipse External Tools Configuration JRE solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Another way to set this, is to use in your build.xml:

```
<project name="xyz" default="all">
<property name="ant.build.javac.target" value="1.7" />
...
```

This global parameter (`ant.build.javac.target`) specifies the project target to be compatible with JDK 7.

Answer (score 0):

In the `javac` task, try specifying the Java compiler by setting the executable attribute as follows:

```
<property name="JDK1.7.dir" location="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7" />
<property name="javac1.7" location="${JDK1.7.dir}/bin/javac" />

<target name="compile-tests">
  <javac executable="${javac1.7}" 
      fork="yes"
      includeantruntime="false" 
      srcdir="${test.dir}"
      destdir="${build.dir}" >
    <classpath refid="class.path" />
  </javac>
</target>
```

Comment: What is javac task? Sorry I'm newbee in eclipse, I'm trying to compile library tamplate for processing. I put your code at te begining of `build.xml` ( https://github.com/processing/processing-library-template/blob/master/resources/build.xml ) of processing library template  which I try to compile. The probelm prevail

Comment: javac task is the task used to compile Java based programs/file.